# Wired Network has Random Intermittent Failures

Tags: windows-7, networking, wired

I just built a new computer running Windows 7 with an Intel 82579V Gigabit on the motherboard. Since last night while playing an online game, I have occasionally noticed sudden network failures where I either time out of my game or severely lag for 10 seconds before the game catches up.

My other network hardware and setup remains unchanged during this build.

I have never had issues with my internet connectivity from my ISP.

The problem is not consistent and I'm not sure how to repeat it. I was playing my online game for several hours and then suddenly started having problems every 5 minutes with disconnecting.

I can watch the network utilization in the Windows Task manager drop suddenly and then spike back when I reconnect to the game. Similar visual seen on the Tomato software on my router.

So far I've grabbed the latest drivers for the network chip from my motherboard manufacturer's website and turned off Teredo. I also made sure no power saving features were enabled on the network chip in the device manager.

What is causing my disconnects? What testing can I do to narrow down the problem scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much deliberation, I was able to conclusively decide that my problem was not on my wired network but my ISP. After multiple phone calls, the connection has been working just fine.